# Cascade in Hibernate one-to-many and many-to-many

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, one-to-many, cascade

I'm new in hibernate and I'm trying to understand the cascade concept.

I have studied the hibernate documentation, but some things are unclear to me:

1) How to use cascade in a bidirectional one-to-many Relation:

So lets say I have a Parent, and a parent can have zero or more Children.

The behaviour should be:
- if a Parent-object is deleted, all of its Children should be deleted too.
- It should be possible, to delete a single Child. So only the relation/connection between parent and this single Child should be deleted, but not the Parent.

My Parent config file would look like this:

```
<class name="Parent" table="Parent">
     <set name="children" table="Child" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="Parent_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Child" />
        </set>
</class>
```

The Child config file:

```
<class name="Child" table="Child">
    <many-to-one name="parent" class="Parent" fetch="select">
            <column name="Parent_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

How do I specify the cascade behavior (in Child or Parent)?
And how does my DAO delete this Child?
I guess by configurating cascade correctly its quite simple,
so that a simple delete like this

```
public void deleteChild(Child child){
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();    
    session.delete(childObject);
    tx.commit();
}
```

is enough to remove also the connection in the parent object, 
or does the DAO need to remove the connection by hand in this manner:

```
public void deleteChild(Child child){
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();    
    Parent p = child.getParent();
    p.getChildren().remove(p);
    session.delete(childObject);
    session.update(p);
    tx.commit();
}
```

2) My second Question is similar to the first, but this time I use a bidirectional many-to-many relation:

Lets say :
- A class User and a User can be member of zero or more Groups
- A Group can contain zero or more Users

So if I delete a User, then only the User and the relation to the Group should be deleted and not the Groups, in which this User was member and vice versa.

If I delete a Group, than only the Group and the relation to the User should be deleted, but not the Users that were member of this Group.

The config file for User:

```
<class name="User" table="User">
    <set name="groups" table="UserGroupMember" inverse="true">    <!-- inverse = true, since i want that the Group adds User as member -->    
        <key column="User_id" />         
        <many-to-many column="group_id" class="Group"/>    
    </set> 
</class>
```

and the config for the Group:

```
<class name="Group" table="Groups">
    <set name="users" table="UserGroupMember" inverse="false">        
            <key column="Group_id" />         
            <many-to-many column="User_id" class="User" />    
    </set>
</class>
```

How do i set cascade in this case?
And what about the DAO?

Is a simple session.delete(group) enough or does the relations need to be deleted by hand like this:

```
public void deleteGroup(Group group)
{
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    for (User u: group.getUsers())
    {
        u.getGroups().remove(group);
        session.update(u);
    }

    group.getUsers().clear();
    session.update(group);
    session.delete(group);
    tx.commit();
}
```